# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get' when testing Flask requests

Tags: python, pytest

Good afternoon,
I am developing some unit tests for my Flask application. It is my first time trying to develop unit tests for a Flask app, but I am currently getting this error when trying to test GET requests.

```
    def testTagCategories():
>       response = client.get("/forum")
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have been struggling to find what the problem is, as I have followed all the steps required in the Flask documentation. Here is the code.

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_client():
    flask_app = app()
    testing_client = flask_app.test_client()
    ctx = flask_app.app_context()
    ctx.push()
    yield testing_client
    ctx.pop()

@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()

@pytest.fixture()
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

Finally, this is one of the functions where I get the error. Thanks in advance.

```
def test_access():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert (response.status_code == 200)
```

Comment: You're not using fixtures correctly. See the docs https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/fixtures.html

Comment: @flakes but what is exactly not going well? I have literally copied and pasted what was explained in the Flask documentation, and it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also learning to unit test a flask controller so take my answer with a pinch of salt.

But in the failing code (like below) there appears to be no client instance and thus you cannot call the get method.

```
def test_access():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert (response.status_code == 200)
```

I'm sure there is a nicer way of doing it by having the client created before every test fixture (that's how I would do it in another language I'm more familiar with like C# with setup / teardown before each test).

But something like this works for me:

```
from app import application

def test_access():
    client = application.test_client()
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    html = response.data.decode()
    assert 'xxx' in html
```

in my app directory there is an __init__.py with application = Flask(__name__) in it. That's what from app import application is importing.

Would love to hear a better solution from someone though.

Edit: On the function that is causing an error, trying changing the signature to the following:

```
def test_access(client):
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on a Udacity course and chatgpt found the error for me. I had this in my test_flaskr.py:

```
def setUp(self):
    """Define test variables and initialize app."""
    self.app = create_app()
    self.client = self.app.test_client
    self.database_name = "trivia_test"
    self.database_path ="postgres://{}:{}@{}/{}".format('student', 'student','localhost:5432', self.database_name)
    setup_db(self.app, self.database_path)
```

I needed the "()" after self.app.test_client